# How can I write this nested query?

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, wcf-ria-services

I am struggling to write a query that depends on the results of two tables that have their own query operations.

Can anyone help me?

---

My work around is the following:

```
    public IQueryable<Message> GetMessages(int user_id)
    {
        // Get MessageReceiver tables that share receiver id
        IQueryable<MessageReceiver> messageReceivers = GetMessageReceivers().Where(messageReceiver => messageReceiver.receiver_id == user_id);

        List<Message> messages = new List<Message>();
        foreach (MessageReceiver messageReceiver in messageReceivers)
        {
            foreach (Message message in DataContext.Messages)
            {
                if (message.id == messageReceiver.message_id)
                {
                    messages.Add(message);
                }
            }
        }

        return messages.AsQueryable<Message>();
    }
```

Regards,
Scott Nimrod

Comment: Sorry, I haven't returned back to this issue to verify it yet.

Comment: Yes. Both tables belong to the same data context.

Comment: I've updated my solution to take account of the single data context. One last question, which ORM are you using?  LINQ to SQL?  Entity Framework?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as the MessageRecievers are loaded from the same data context as the Messages we can join them in the same query.

```
public IQueryable<Message> GetMessages(int user_id)
{    
    // Get MessageReceiver tables that share receiver id
    var messageReceivers = GetMessageReceivers().Where(messageReceiver => messageReceiver.receiver_id == user_id);

    // get all messages that have been recieved by a user
    var messages = from m in DataContext.Messages
                   join r in messageReceivers
                   on m.id equals r.message_id
                   select m;                  

    //return the messages
    return messages;
}
```

This will result in SQL similar to the following: (assuming that you are using LINQ to SQL or LINQ to EF with a Microsoft SQL provider)

```
SELECT [t0].[id], ... other columns ...
FROM [Messages] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [MessageReceivers] AS [t1] ON [t0].[id] = [t1].[message_id]
```

Comment: I would caution that this type of approach only works in scenarios where you have a limited amount of potential IDs that match.  If you exceed a certain number, LINQ will error out that you have too many parameters.

Comment: Good point, I will update my response. I was hoping that the OP would respond to my question because the ID list might be un-necessary depending on where the MessageReceiver collection comes from.